# Lie Bracket on Suitable Associative Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, math-history, noncommutative-algebra

This question is somewhat naive. Please see the following proof before reading the question itself.

Let $L$ be a vector space over a field $\Bbb{F}.$ Assume there is an associative multiplication on $L$ so that $L$ is an associative ring, and denote this multiplication simply as $xy$ for $x,y\in L$. Furthermore, suppose this multiplication to be compatible with scaling, that is $\alpha\in\Bbb{F},$ then $\alpha x = x\alpha\in L$ for all $x\in L$ ($L$ should be a left and right $\Bbb{F}$ vector space). Define $[x,y]=xy-yx$ for all $x,y\in L.$ Then $[-,-]:L\times L \longrightarrow L$ is a Lie bracket.

*Proof:* 
It is clear that $[-,-]$ is anti-commutative, and bilinear. We only need to show that it satisfies the Jacobi identity. That is

$$[[x,y],z]+[[y,z],x]+[[z,x],y]=0.$$

One readily sees that this is equivalent to

$$(xy)z-(yx)z-z(xy)+z(yx)+(yz)x-(zy)x-x(yz)+x(zy)+(zx)y-(xz)y-y(zx)+y(xz)=0.$$

The previous equation is certainly true when the multiplication defined earlier is associative. Therefore $L$ is a Lie algebra. $\Box$

So here's the question:

> 1) Is it true that an algebra defined in this way is a Lie algebra?

An example of such an associative algebra is the $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb{F}).$

> 2) If so, is there any name which separates these from the classical Lie algebras?

There is rich theory surrounding classical Lie algebras, especially their connection to Lie groups. This motivates the next question.

> 3) Is there any significance in viewing an associative algebra in this way?

Comment: Well, most of the time this associative multiplication you're assuming will not exist.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)

Comment: You did build a functor from the associative algebra to the Lie algebra. There is another functor from the Lie algebra to associative algebra, which send $\mathfrak g$ to $U \mathfrak g$, the universal enveloping algebra. There are adjoint functors.

Comment: I understand this is not the case for division algebras. But for an arbitrary vector space? You can always define one, although it may not be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 1) is even true in the more general case that $(A,\cdot)$ is a *pre-Lie algebra*, where the product $x\cdot y$ need not be associative, but just *semi-associative*. If $(a,b,c)=a\cdot(b\cdot c)-(a\cdot b)\cdot c$ denotes the associator, then $A$ is called a *pre-Lie algebra* with associated Lie algebra $L(A)$, if
$$
x\cdot y-y\cdot x=[x,y],
$$

$$
(x,y,z)=(y,x,z)
$$

Note that $[x,y]$ is a Lie bracket; the proof is similar to the associative case. We have
\begin{align}
[x,[y,z]]+[y,[z,x]]+[z,[x,y]] &= (y,x,z)+(z,y,x)+(x,z,y)-(x,y,z)-(y,z,x)-(z,x,y)\\
 & =0.
\end{align}

Of course, if we take $A$ as an associative algebra, we have $(x,y,z)=(y,x,z)=0$.

For 2), be carefull with the term "classical Lie algebras", which denotes the series $A_n,B_n,C_n,D_n$ of simple Lie algebras. By *Ado's theorem*, any finite-dimensional Lie algebra is isomorphic to a matrix Lie algebra with bracket $[A,B]=AB-BA$. Over fields of prime characetristic this has been shown by Iwasawa.

3) Yes, there is a significance in geometry and physics to consider "Lie-admissible algebras".

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes it's true if the multiplication is associative.

2) I don't know if such algebras have a name. Notice that over $\mathbb C$, every finite-dimensional Lie algebra is a "concrete" Lie algebra, i.e is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak gl(V)$ for $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$, so in particular it is obtained from your construction, starting with an associative algebra and forgetting multiplication.

3) There is a link between associative algebras and Lie algebra : you have a functor in both way which gives you an adjunction $\text{Hom}_{\rm Lie}(\mathfrak g, Lie(A)) \cong \text{Hom}_{\rm Ass}(U \mathfrak g, A)$. But this is in no way an equivalence of category as usually $U \mathfrak g$ is much bigger that $\mathfrak g$ (see [the PWB theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Birkhoff%E2%80%93Witt_theorem)).

Probably looking at the universal enveloping algebra and quantum groups can answer most of your questions.